# merging of two tables based on primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table with some entries same, eg
table A:

```
ID         value        type
1          1            2
2          3            2
3          3            2
```

table B:

```
ID        value        type
2          3            1
3          3            1 
4          1            1
```

I want to merge them so that resulting table looks like

table C:

```
ID        value        type
2          3            2
3          3            2
4          1            1
```

ie , remove the rows that are not in table A, display rows that have duplicate in table A with table A's type and also display those rows that are not in Table A.

Till now i have done UNION command to remove duplicate

```
 select * from table A union select * from table B
```

but how to get type from table A? can this be done or i have to separately update them.

Comment: If you "remove the rows that are not in table A", why is the row with id `4` in table C?

Comment: ... remove the rows that are not in table A.... also display those rows that are not in Table A... can you explain better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT b.id,b.value,
       COALESCE(a.type,b.type) as type
FROM TableB b
LEFT JOIN TableA a
 ON(a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: Beside from mixing `A` and `B` , did I miss anything else? @Strawberry

Comment: I think that was it - although the source data set is a little too threadbare to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want

```
select b.id, b.value, ifnull(a.type,b.type) as type
from b 
left join a 
on b.id = a.id;
```

Comment: @sagi's answer looks equivalent to me

Comment: @sagi's answer has the advantage that it conforms to the ansi sql standard. It just means that it's more portable.